# Why Java behave this way when overloading methods?

Tags: java, overloading, boxing, autoboxing

Given the following code:

```
public class Clazz {

    private static String foo(Integer value) {
        return "Integer";
    }

    private static String foo(float value) {
        return "float";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(foo(10));
        System.out.println(foo(10f));
    }

}
```

Why does it print this?

```
float
float
```

I would expect the following output:

```
Integer
float
```

Comment: Because you use a wrapper. Type widening takes predecence before Wrapper classes.

Comment: It's interpreting your number as a float rather than autoboxing it to an `Integer`. If you overloaded for `int` instead of `Integer`, you would get the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is not a primitive as float.

To get what you want, you should use:

```
System.out.println(foo(new Integer(10)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that. i have a feeling its not the correct type

```
Interget interger = 10;
System.out.println(foo(interger));
System.out.println(foo(10f));
```